# Optimize PostgreSQL query with aggregations, group by for huge dataset

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, query-optimization

I have the below query in PostgreSQL 9.5 which is running slow having the test  `fact` table with 22000 rows, `store` table 295 rows and `product` table 10 rows.

```
create table calc_base as
select a.ticket_id ticket_id, 
       b.product_id,  
       b.product_desc,
       a.promotion_flag promo_flag,
       sum(quantity) num_units,
       sum(sales) num_sales
from fact a
       inner join product b on a.product_id = b.product_id    
where store_id in (select store_id from store)
and b.product_id in (select product_id from fact 
                     group by 1 
                     order by count(distinct ticket_id) desc limit 5000) 
group by 1,2,3,4;
```

Here is the list of indexes for this query:

```
--Add primary keys
ALTER TABLE  PRODUCT   ADD PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCT_ID);
ALTER TABLE  STORE   ADD PRIMARY KEY (STORE_ID);
ALTER TABLE  CUSTOMER   ADD PRIMARY KEY (CUSTOMER_ID);
ALTER TABLE  TIME   ADD PRIMARY KEY (DATE_ID); 

-- ADD FORIENG KEY without constraint
ALTER TABLE FACT ADD  FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCT_ID) REFERENCES PRODUCT (PRODUCT_ID);
ALTER TABLE FACT ADD  FOREIGN KEY (STORE_ID)   REFERENCES STORE (STORE_ID);
ALTER TABLE FACT ADD  FOREIGN KEY (DATE_ID)    REFERENCES TIME (DATE_ID);
ALTER TABLE FACT ADD  FOREIGN KEY (SEGMENT_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER (CUSTOMER_ID);

-- create indexes for forien keys
CREATE INDEX ON fact(PRODUCT_ID);
CREATE INDEX ON fact(STORE_ID);
CREATE INDEX ON fact(DATE_ID);
```

How can I optimize this query to be faster. I need professional suggestions for optimizing aggregations and group by in big dataset because my real dataset has 3 billion transactions and I have to run this query with 3 billion rows.

### UPDATE :

I ran the below query without `where store_id in (select store_id from store)` using bigger dataset, `fact` 2 million rows, `product` 344117 rows.

```
create table calc_base as
select a.ticket_id ticket_id,
    b.product_id, 
    b.product_desc,
    a.promotion_flag promo_flag,
    sum(quantity_abs) kpi_units,
    sum(sales_abs) kpi_sales
from fact a
    inner join product b on a.product_id = b.product_id    
where b.product_id in (select product_id from fact 
            group by 1 order by count(distinct ticket_id) desc limit 5000 ) 
group by 1,2,3,4;
```

Query plan:

```
"GroupAggregate  (cost=472629.13..505129.13 rows=1000000 width=39) (actual time=8230.069..11230.872 rows=2000000 loops=1)"
"  Group Key: a.ticket_id, b.product_id, b.product_desc, a.promotion_flag"
"  Buffers: shared hit=49090, temp read=19225 written=19225"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=472629.13..475129.13 rows=1000000 width=39) (actual time=8230.053..9771.612 rows=2000000 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: a.ticket_id, b.product_id, b.product_desc, a.promotion_flag"
"        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 98968kB"
"        Buffers: shared hit=49090, temp read=19225 written=19225"
"        ->  Hash Join  (cost=300396.32..357345.29 rows=1000000 width=39) (actual time=5424.131..6357.988 rows=2000000 loops=1)"
"              Hash Cond: (a.product_id = b.product_id)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=49076, temp read=6847 written=6847"
"              ->  Seq Scan on fact a  (cost=0.00..39449.00 rows=2000000 width=25) (actual time=0.009..129.726 rows=2000000 loops=1)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=19449"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=298245.59..298245.59 rows=172058 width=26) (actual time=5423.385..5423.385 rows=914 loops=1)"
"                    Buckets: 262144  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2101kB"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=29627, temp read=6847 written=6847"
"                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=283334.26..298245.59 rows=172058 width=26) (actual time=5334.482..5423.097 rows=914 loops=1)"
"                          Hash Cond: (b.product_id = fact.product_id)"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=29627, temp read=6847 written=6847"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on product b  (cost=0.00..13616.17 rows=344117 width=20) (actual time=0.007..40.339 rows=344117 loops=1)"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=10175"
"                          ->  Hash  (cost=283328.34..283328.34 rows=473 width=6) (actual time=5334.458..5334.458 rows=914 loops=1)"
"                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 51kB"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=19452, temp read=6847 written=6847"
"                                ->  Limit  (cost=283322.43..283323.61 rows=473 width=14) (actual time=5334.213..5334.288 rows=914 loops=1)"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=19452, temp read=6847 written=6847"
"                                      ->  Sort  (cost=283322.43..283323.61 rows=473 width=14) (actual time=5334.210..5334.235 rows=914 loops=1)"
"                                            Sort Key: (count(DISTINCT fact.ticket_id)) DESC"
"                                            Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 67kB"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=19452, temp read=6847 written=6847"
"                                            ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=268296.69..283301.42 rows=473 width=14) (actual time=2768.464..5333.807 rows=914 loops=1)"
"                                                  Group Key: fact.product_id"
"                                                  Buffers: shared hit=19449, temp read=6847 written=6847"
"                                                  ->  Sort  (cost=268296.69..273296.69 rows=2000000 width=14) (actual time=2756.509..3782.823 rows=2000000 loops=1)"
"                                                        Sort Key: fact.product_id"
"                                                        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 48080kB"
"                                                        Buffers: shared hit=19449, temp read=6014 written=6014"
"                                                        ->  Seq Scan on fact  (cost=0.00..39449.00 rows=2000000 width=14) (actual time=0.003..321.660 rows=2000000 loops=1)"
"                                                              Buffers: shared hit=19449"
"Planning time: 5.449 ms"
"Execution time: 12673.017 ms"
```

Can I optimize it more according to the query plan?

Comment: Try it at on bigger portion of data or on the whole real data set and place execution plan from it. With more data you will see if there are some sorts on disk how buffers are really used for big data etc. This test cannot really show you anything significant.

Comment: Note: `where store_id in (select store_id from store)` is not needed, since store_id is a foreign key.... *I need professional suggestions for optimizing*

Comment: 87ms seconds seems quite fast to me.

Comment: Try this: http://pasted.co/2d5daf10

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name in compare with other db like EXASOL it is slow. the time measurement unit is millisecond right? so it is 87 milliseconds.

Comment: Yes that's 87 **milli** seconds - how fast do you need that to be? And if Exasol is fast enough for you then why don't you use it?

Comment: So you want to find the top 5k products from only 10 products? Please use a more realistic dataset for profiling. -- Also, I don't think we could compare an in-memory db with a persistent one, they are designed for different use cases.

Comment: I am benchmarking postgres and exasol to see if postgres perform good then we can use it for some projects. Exasol is so expensive. Exasol single node is executing this query with 50 ms including planning time.

Comment: I edited the code to be clear. Is there any way to force postgres server use all Ram or most of it for running queries?

Comment: If you omit the `where store_id in(...)`, you'll probably get below 70 ms.

Comment: @joop I deleted store_id where clause and exe time after running query for several times went down to near 82ms.

Comment: You might also want to use Postgres 9.6 instead of 98.5 because it has several performance enhancements in the area of aggregation and can make (limited) use of multiple CPUs for a single statement. Did you try my alternate version of your query?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes your query is performing almost the same! Is the version 9.6 stable?

Comment: 9.6 is stable, yes (otherwise it wouldn't have been released)

Comment: Note: the edit removed the `LIMIT 3000` from the subquery. Now the subquery is useless and can be removed completely.

Comment: Sorry It was removed by mistake. Edited.